# How can I make a grid of clickable images from a list of data in WPF?

Tags: mvvm, wpf-controls, binding, clickable-image

I am a seasoned C and Java programmer, but an absolute WPF newbie.

I am creating a kiosk application that will display a list of images of products that the user will click to see product details and maybe place an order.

I am trying to structure my app with MVVM Foundation because I am used to the benefits of structure and tests.

I wonder what is the most natural way to create a grid of clickable images that will fill the screen left to right, top to bottom (or the other way round, I have no exact requirements).

Any image should be bound to an object that will become current and be displayed in the next screen.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK! Listen up! Here is how you do that! :)
1) Use ItemsControl together with UniformGrid to get automatic aligment

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid>
            </UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <Button Width="50" Height="50"/>
    <Button Width="50" Height="50"/>
    <Button Width="50" Height="50"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

2) Populate ItemsControl with data from your viewmodel

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ImageList}"...

public ObservableCollection<ClickableImage> ImageList
{
    get { return m_ImageList;}
}

... constructor
{
    m_ImageList = new ObservableCollection<ClickableImage>();
    m_ImageList.Add(new ClickableImage("image.png");
}
```

TADAAAA!

Comment: Looks great! I will try it asap.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go. I still have not ironed all the wrinkles in my dynamic image list, but yes, they appear in the right order.

Answer (score 3):

I have refined a little the code. Here is the namespace declaration

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestSandbox.ViewModels"
```

the DataContext

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModel1/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

and the uniformGrid

```
<ItemsControl Name="imageList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}" BorderBrush="#FFA90606" Background="#FFE70F0F">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Margin="50">
            </UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- The Image binding -->
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=image}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

here is the C# code in the view model

```
    public List<Product> Products {get; set; }

    public ViewModel1()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
        Products.Add(MakeProduct(@"..\images\beemovie.jpg"));
        Products.Add(MakeProduct(@"..\images\darkknight.jpg"));
        Products.Add(MakeProduct(@"..\images\matrix.jpg"));
        Products.Add(MakeProduct(@"..\images\milo.jpg"));
        Products.Add(MakeProduct(@"..\images\superhero.jpg"));
        Products.Add(MakeProduct(@"..\images\twilight.jpg"));
        Products.Add(MakeProduct(@"..\images\xfiles.jpg"));
    }

    public Product MakeProduct(string path)
    {
        return new Product(path, MakeImage(path));
    }

    public BitmapImage MakeImage(string path)
    {
        BitmapImage bmpi = new BitmapImage();
        bmpi.BeginInit();
        bmpi.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
        bmpi.EndInit();
        return bmpi;
    }
```

Comment: how does class Product look like?

Comment: How to bind the images to view model? I see no property "image" in your view model. I need to know since I am facing the similar problem at this moment. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Saved me a ton of headache lol. Been trying for hours to accomplish this with grids or datagrids. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In ViewModel add `ObservableList<ClickableImage> m_Images` as public property.
In XAML use `ListView` for displaying `ClickableImage`.
Create datatemplate for `ClickableImage` with Image and raised command uppon click.

On the XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=OnClickCommand}"/>
```

On the ViewModel:

```
public ICommand OnClickCommand {
    get
    {
        return  new RelayCommand(aram => this.Click(), param => this.CanClick);
    }
}
public void Click() {
        //i was clicked!  
        globalBigImageViewModel.BigImageContent = m_Image;
}
```

Comment: Aha, thank you, The last point is very interesting but still escapes me: how can I raise a command on a click? I am using transparent buttons over images because I could not find how to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I think I created a satisfactory clickable-image here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720463/creating-a-clickable-image-in-wpf.
The question still open is how do I populate a grid of controls from a  List