# Creating a clickable image in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-foundation, clickable-image

I want to make a user control that shows an image and can invoke a command when clicked.
Later I want to bind a list of these controls to a list of products.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this very straight forward approach

```
<Grid>
        <Button Height="50" Width="50">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="yourimage.png"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

    </Grid>

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           // do smt
        }
```

Comment: This was the most straight forward approach I've seen without having to override all the visual styles for the button.

Comment: I've gone with this approach, but reusability goes out the window, since you're effectively hard-coding in the image name. But, it fits my needs.

Comment: @jrandomuser see my answer then.

Comment: ok but no hover image ? it does not act as a real button here

Answer (score 8):

Well, after a little more fiddling, a simple button does the job. Here it is:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DisplayProductCommand}" >
   <Image Source="..\Images\my-beautiful-product.jpg"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: This is not a clickable image, this is a button with an image inside it. I'm baffled that this is marked as the accepted answer. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21597209/161250) should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do this, but one simple solution would be to use a button (maybe style away the border and background), and use the image as the content of the button.

You can later use a ListBox or similar, and override the DataTemplate to use the button and an image for each product.

Comment: This is in fact the first route I was taking, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
   <Image Name="imageFoo" Source="/AppFoo;component/Foo.png" Width="32" Cursor="Hand" MouseUp="imageFoo_MouseUp"/>

    private void imageFoo_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, mico, for not completely understanding your requirement. Let me leave my answer there just in case anyone needs a quick way to have a clickable image.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about you guys but `PreviewMouseDown` and `TouchUp` worked completely fine along with my binding:

```
<Image x:Name="bla" Source="{Binding blabla}" ... TouchDown="bla_TouchDown" PreviewMouseDown="bla_PreviewMouseDown">
```

I am using VS 2015